# MIPS Print multiples of 2 and 3 in the range 0 to n

Tags: mips

I have just started MIPS and I am trying to print all numbers that are multiples of 2 and 3 between a range of 0 to n. I have coded a program that can print the numbers from 0 to n already.
I know that I should try use the "and  $t0, $v0, 2" and the "and  $t0, $v0, 3" to check if it is a multiple but I get mixed up in the MIPS code as it is very confusing for a beginner. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        main:                
                      
    la  $a0, prompt             
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    li  $v0, 5                  
    syscall
    li    $t0, 1      
    move $t2,$v0;
loop:                 
    bgt  $t0, $t2 end  
    move $a0, $t0     
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall
    li   $a0, '\n'      
    li   $v0, 11
    syscall
    add  $t0, $t0 1   
    b    loop        
end:
    jr   $ra
    .data
prompt:
    .asciiz "Enter a number: "
```

Comment: To check if a value is a multiple of 2, you'd AND with 1, not 2. For multiples of 3, you'd divide by 3 (using `div` or `divu`) and check if the remainder (i.e. `hi`) is 0.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Sorry for my ignorance but how would I go about printing those that are multiples of 2 and 3.

Comment: By performing the already mentioned operations, and if the result is non-zero, skip past the printing code using a conditional branch instruction.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach for this problem

```
#for (int i =0;i<=n; i++)

#if (i%2 ==0) && (i%3==0)

#print i;

.data

prompt: .asciiz "enter value for n: "

newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text

.globl main

main:

li $t5 0   #initialising i = 0

#for printing prompt

li $v0 4

la $a0 prompt

syscall

#user input reading

li $v0 5

syscall

move $t1 $v0

#displaying on console

move $a0 $t0

li $v0 1

syscall

move $v0 $t0

loop:

beq $t5 $t1 end         #checking if i=n

#checking multiples of 2 
   
div $t2 $t5 2

mfhi $t2                #remainder

beq $t2 0 equal         #if remainder 0, jump to equal

addi $t5 $t5 1          #increment i by 1

j loop

equal:

#beq $t2 $t3 answer

#checking multiples of 3 

div $t3 $t5 3       

mfhi $t3        #remainder

beq $t3 0 equal2    #if remainder 0, jump to equal2

addi $t5 $t5 1          #if remainder != 0, incrementing i and jumping to loop

j loop

equal2:     
        
beq $t2 $t3 answer  #if both remainder equal to zero, jump to answer




answer:

move $a0 $t5            #moving the value of i for which i is a multiple of 2 and 3

li $v0 1        #printing the answer

syscall

#giving space of a line

li $v0,4

la $a0, newline

syscall

addi $t5 $t5 1      #incrementing i

j loop

#terminating

end:

li $v0, 10

syscall
```